# Using word 'model' in package name creates resource and not package

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to create a package called `sc.edu.csce740.model` in **Eclipse**. When I do so it ends up creating a folder and not a package.

But if I use any other word such as `apples` such as `sc.edu.csce740.apples` then it does successfully create the package.

I have also tried creating `apples` first and then refactoring but it changes itself to a folder (resource).

Is this a reserved word? Eclipse bug?

[image]

---

Eclipse Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)

Eclipse Build id: 20171005-1200

Comment: I can't reproduce in Eclipse Oxygen.1 Release (4.7.1), Build id: 20170914-1200, interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds to me as if "model" has been set as an **exclusion filter**. Go to the project's Java Build Path and check if the owner source folder has any exclusion.

Comment: Hero. Hero. Hero.

Comment: :-) Glad I've been useful to you.